# Deep Links not opening properly in a Microsoft Teams Android app with Adaptive Cards

Tags: android, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I'm creating adaptive cards in Microsoft Teams with this following deep link:

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000aaa00b/my-tab-id?context=%7B%22channelId%22:%2219:aaaaaaaa000000000000000000000000@thread.tacv2%22,%22subEntityId%22:%22link/2%22%7D&webUrl=https://my-app/url
```

This works as expected in Desktop and PC browser - opens the link in the existing tab and sends the subEntity parameter to application context.

However, it's not working on android phones - the link quickly refresh only the current opened channel.

Am I missing any parameter? I followed [Generate a deep link to your tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#generate-a-deep-link-to-your-tab) doc and same error.

Comment: We are tried to repro the scenario with the following deeplink.It's working fine with android app also.
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/59b691f9-f321-4a79-b760-35e0083XXXXX/test123?webUrl=https://my-app/url&label=Test&context={"subEntityId": "1234","channelId": "19%3aXXXXX6051a7a4171815916dbd18a2fb2%40thread.tacv2"}
Could you please check it once or share the repro steps, so that we can try it from our end.

Comment: Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved with above suggestion or still looking for any help?

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT Still an issue, just for android and just for Teams tab. I recorded a video showing that, "View Need" button has exactly this URL I sent (and the same you replied), it quickly blinks the screen but nothing happens. Other actions like "Add Solution", which doesn't use internal tab, works fine on Android too https://youtu.be/QCQcgIIeapY

Comment: Could you please share the adaptive card json, so that we can try it from our end.

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT here I'm sharing the adaptive card json: https://gist.github.com/rfaga/1503f4bbfaa906be581e58eb02afc228

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft the issue is still not resolved

Comment: Could you please tried with this sample. add button with deeplink in TeamsMessagingExtensionsSearchBot.cs file.
https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/50.teams-messaging-extensions-search